# How to rearrange Slider Elements in mobile with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

**I want to rearrange my slider in mobile version.I want slider start not with first but with thirt elemenet of slider.i wrote startSlide function on position 2 but still doesnt work plase help guys .**

```
      jQuery('.js-a1-wlan-slider').slick({
    
      // normal options...
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: "26px",
      focusOnSelect: false,
      arrows: true,
      prevArrow: '<a class="a1-wlan-slider-boxes-prev deactive"></a>',
      nextArrow: '<a class="a1-wlan-slider-boxes-next"></a>',
      initialSlide : 2,
      dots: true,
      mobileFirst: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1023,
          settings: "unslick"
        }

      ]
  });
```

Comment: Where did you found that you need to use `startSlide`? When I look at documentation it says you need to use `initialSlide`

Comment: u just right man thank you so much i didnt see it ;)

Comment: but still doenst work slide begin with first element even i put initialslide:2 do i need  do anything else ?

Comment: please update your question with the new code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I updated ;)